# MouseDoubleClick routed event doesn't fire up in EventTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My question is fairly simple, because it works in other cases but not with double click mouse event. I want to make editable tab items, and its almost done. Maybe code will clear the situation:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox x:Name="HeaderEditMode" Text="{Binding Header, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderDisplayMode" Text="{Binding Header, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <StackPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDoubleClick">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderEditMode"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderDisplayMode"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderEditMode"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderDisplayMode"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </StackPanel.Triggers>
    </StackPanel>
```

If you change MouseDoubleClick to for example to MouseDown or MouseEnter it works perfectly. Any suggestions?

Comment: `StackPanel` does not support `MouseDoubleClick` event. It's implemented in `Control` class. You could do `Control.MouseDoubleClick` but then you still need some `Control` to trigger this event

Comment: This is usefull. Ok I will try to find sth that triger this event. You can wrap up this in button but then you lose all styles that i was using :/. Maybe make it transparent then.

Comment: Sorry, I misguided you. Just checked and [`Control.MouseDoubleClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx)  is direct routed event which means it's triggered **only on the `Control` itself** so you cannot catch it on `StackPanel` anyway

Comment: But fi you wrap it up in <Button> it works. You can catch this in button trigers and then update visibility accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your `TextBlock` in a `ContentControl`, and attach the `MouseDoubleClick` trigger to that instead.